# How to convert a Word document to a webpage in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am working on a publishing portal. I will be getting the articles in Word format from authors which will be having images and styles (italic,bold). I need to convert these documents to a web page and show as it is in the Word document. How can I do it in [SharePoint 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharePoint#Notable_changes_in_SharePoint_2010)?

Comment: No Anuja. I tried this document conversion out of box functionality already.Some conversions are not happening as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

1) imho this question is not about exactly 'SharePoint', but if the word version is 2007 or higher, You can use [OpenXML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2014/01/30/transform-docx-to-html-css-with-high-fidelity-using-powertools-for-open-xml.aspx) to convert.

Beginning from Word 2007, You can "Save as" document in html format. To do it programmatically You need to install Open xml SDK 2.5  + Powertools 3.0, compile the project, and there are examples that convert some files to html. See these links

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425
https://powertools.codeplex.com/releases/view/74771

Additionally, if You have many old files in non-docx format, You can convert them from 'Doc' to 'Docx' via powershell: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/22/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-2-0-to-convert-doc-files-to-docx-files.aspx

2) Or You can use something like Office Web Apps Server and show office documents in browser without conversion. All depends from cases..

Answer (score 0):

You can use office web apps to do this in an easy way. For this you will need office web app servers installed. Once you have it, turn on a site collection feature for office web apps.

You will get additional options for all files for office 2007 and above to open in browser and edit in browser.

Office 2003 documents can be viewed using office web apps but not to edit them. To edit the file in Office Web Apps, open the file in Microsoft Office Excel 2010, Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2010 or in Microsoft Office Word 2010, and then save the file by using one of the supported formats.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience the doc converter services won't get you there. My advise would be to buy a 3rd party product like Aspose (aspose.com) or some other vendor (mind you, I have no commercial relation to Apose at all, just a happy customer) and they offer the libraries that make it quite easu to convert all these different types of files to html, even including pictures. I've used it myself to build a search preview, but that's another story.

Reference: [sharepoint development](https://aufait.in/sharepoint)

Answer (score -3):

Hope this article will help you

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770243(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Please do not only provide links as an answer. Copy in an abstract of the outlines of the article to your answer to make it more stand-alone and helpful :)

Comment: As Robert says, please summarise (not copy) the relevant information. By all means include the link for reference, but links can change or disappear, rendering the answer useless. [mod]